# How to check if object is nullabla to set text on the label xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a double? object and want when He has no value to set text on label "0 mm".

I try like this but not work for me:

```
double? test = weatherBindingData.WeatherDataForecastHourly.List[0].SnowForecast.SnowForecastValue;

        if (!test.HasValue)
        {
            SnowForecast1Day.Text = "0 mm";
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double? test = some value or null;
string str = test?.ToString("0.00 mm") ?? "0 mm";
```

Comment: But with this way when he have a value will be other like 0.00mm all right ?

Comment: @PizhevRacing No. ToString("0.00 mm') is formating the output. e.g. if your double variable is 123.45678 your string would be "123.45 mm". another example if you use ToString("0 mm") your string would be "123 mm".